# Bedeutung von den Sätzen nach dem Muster "Es war der ... , der

Tags: meaning

Vergleichen Sie die beiden Beispielsätze:

> Der Minister hat den Vorschlag angenommen.
>
> Es war der Minister, der den Vorschlag angenommen hat.

Wo liegt der Unterschied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Unterschied liegt im *Satzfokus*. Die Aussage (Proposition) ist dieselbe, egal ob man sagt

> Der Minister hat den Vorschlag angenommen.
>
> Es war der Minister, der den Vorschlag angenommen hat.
>
> Es war der Vorschlag, den der Minister angenommen hat.

Aber im ersten Fall wird der Sachverhalt  neutral geschildert; im zweiten wird darauf hingewiesen, daß der Minister (nicht etwa sein Stellvertreter, oder aber der Premierminister) die Entscheidung getroffen hat. Im dritten wird betont, daß der Vorschlag angenommen wurde (und nicht etwa der Gegenvorschlag oder die zuvor bestehende Regelung). Jede dieser drei Formulierungen kann angemessen sein, je nachdem, welche Annahmen (Präsuppositionen) bei Sprecher und Hörer vorliegen.